# Adding and using resources files on Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, resources

I have to use text files files on my project on Visual Studio, and instead of working with file streams I'd like to add them directly to the build.

I have added them to the solution explorer and edited their properties changing the **Item Type** to **Resource**.

Now I want to know how may I access their content, say, put their text into a string. (I'm using C++)

PS: Is there a good tutorial about using resource files? Couldn't find any recent tutorial for visual studio.

Comment: What about reading this [**Resource Files (Visual Studio)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7zxb70x7.aspx) or this [**Using Resources**](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/resources.html) links amongst the other (felt a million) simple google query results?!? (OT: If you really _'hatecomputers'_, that's the wrong attitude getting on the topic ;) ...)

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: **First link**: OK! Why not start with **Creating a new resource**? First thing I see: "In Solution Explorer [...] then click Add Resource on the shortcut menu." There is no such option! In fact, none of those work because I'm on express and it doesn't have a "resource view". 

**Second link**: After many talk, suddenly he says: **"First lets take a very simple resource script"** and shows a script. Again: WHAT?! Where am I suposed to write that? How does a script in what-language-is-that help me accessing my resource? How is that even easier than working with File streams?

Comment: _'because I'm on express'_ Yes, you have limited capabilities and features with it. _'Where am I suposed to write that?'_ Well, you seem to need getting workarounds, to deal with the restricted capabilities/features :P ...

Comment: Sure... yeah it's always like that. Everytime I come to this forum when there is NO OTHER SOURCE, it's like, the last trial, and evertime it's the same thing, downvoted, flame... and I always promisse myself to never comeback. This kind of thing just make me stay away from programming, even though I really like it, when I see the kind of people that I would need to work with following this path, I just feel disgust.

Comment: Who's being _"flaming"_ you here please? Asking for 3rd party resource is simply OT on this site. Don't take anything personally here, that's just mechanics. You want to [(re-)take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), or check [how to ask properly](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). That's all dude ;) ...

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve a user-defined resource from within your executable see the FindResource, LoadResource and LockResource APIs.